# Sequence of natural numbers such that $a_i = \sum_{r=1}^{i+4} d_r$

Tags: number-theory

> Find a sequence of natural numbers $a_i$ such that $\displaystyle a_i = \sum_{r=1}^{i+4} d_r$ where $d_r \neq d_s$ for $r \neq s$ and $d_r$ divides $a_i$ for all $r \in \{ 1, 2, \dots, i+4\}.$

**Attempt:**

Suppose $a_n = d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_{n+4}$ for some $n$. Then we see $a_{n+1} = d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_{n+4}+c$. Then let $c = (d_{n+5}-1)(d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_{n+4})$ and so $a_{n+1} = d_{n+5}(d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_{n+4})$ where $d_{n+5} \neq d_{i}$ for $i = 1,2,\ldots,n+4$. We inductively then establish a sequence $a_i$.

Comment: What does "$d_r$ divides $a_i$" mean? That is, what is $r$ in this statement?

Comment: @MatthewConroy It is as defined in the summation.

Comment: That is still not clear.  Do you mean $d_r$ divides $a_i$ for all $1 \le r \le i+4$?

Comment: @MatthewConroy That is correct.

Comment: In your construction how are you sure that $d_1$ divides $a_{n+1}?$

Comment: @awllower Since by assumption $d_1$ divides $d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_{n+4}$.

Comment: Alright, so it remains to find one such $a_1?$ Also isn't $a_{n+1}$ supposed to be $\sum_{r=1}^{n+5} d_r?$

Comment: @awllower Yeah, I realize my construction is incorrect. What would be a correct one?

Comment: How about $d_{n+5}=d_1+\cdots+d_{n+4}?$

Comment: @awllower How does that work? We have $a_{n+1} = 2(d_1+\cdots+d_n)+d_{n+1}+d_{n+2}+d_{n+3}+d_{n+4}$ and so would need $d_1+\cdots+d_n$ to divide $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42438/discussion-between-awllower-and-user19405892).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in the question body, we first find one $a_1=d_1+\cdots+d_5$ and then inductively find $a_{n+1}.$
For the first task, consider [the second perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) $a_1=28=1+2+4+7+14.$
Then, notice that if $a_n=d_1+\cdots+d_{n+4}$ satisfies the requirements, then $a_{n+1}:=2a_n=d_1+\cdots+d_{n+5}$ also satisfies the requirements where $d_{n+5}:=a_n.$ Thus the sequence $$a_n:=2^{n-1}28$$ satisfies the requirements.

Hope this helps.